# Read SQL Server field text value in Delphi XE with simultaneously character conversion

Tags: sql-server-2005, delphi, encoding, delphi-xe

I have a SQL Server 2005 database with COLLATION `SQL_Latin_General_CP1_CI_AS` and I want to run a query from Delphi XE via ADO. Data in SQL Server is Greek and Latin characters. But in Delphi I get unreadable character strings. How can I manage this problem with Delphi XE ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you say that you have both Greek and Latin characters in the db I guess that you are already using `nvarchar` in the db.

In Delphi you should then use [TWideStringField](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/DB.TWideStringField) for `nvarchar` fields. [TStringField](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/DB.TStringField) is for `varchar` (ansistring).

Field1 contains "γειά σου"

```
StringField := ADODataSet1.FieldByName('Field1') as TStringField;
ShowMessage(StringField.Value);
```

ShowMessage shows "?e??s??"

This works fine

```
WideStringField := ADODataSet1.FieldByName('Field1') as TWideStringField;
ShowMessage(WideStringField.Value);
```

**Edit 1**
If you have `varchar` fields in db you should use `TStringField` and you need to make sure that the "Language for non-Unicode programs" is `Greek(Greece)`.

"Control Panel - Region and Language - Administrative - Change system locale..."

Comment: No, db is a third party and uses varchar fields. If i open a table with SQLManager i can't read the greek characters from WinXP. Anyway I'll try your solution. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Bakas George With `varchar` fields you need to have Greek(Greece) as "Current system locale:". If you still have problems I think it is somewhere else. The test code above works fine with the correct Region and Language Settings.

Comment: If you see this in MSSQL table field: ÈÅÏÄÙÑÏÕ ÃÅÙÑÃÉÏÓ. How could you please converted to win1253 readable Greek from ADO-Delphi XE. Windows Control Panel parameters are as you suggested. Thank you for your time again.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that sometimes UTF-8 is stored in databases in `VarChar` fields, usually from Java programs.

If you see things like `â€"`, there's a good chance that's what is going on.

You could try

```
// Delphi 2009+
UTF8ToUnicodeString(RawByteString( db_value ))

// Delphi 2007 and older
UTF8Decode( db_value )
```

If this is the case, you can also use a [sql function to convert the VarChar fields to NVarChar](http://www.jasontpenny.com/blog/2009/07/31/sql-function-to-get-nvarchar-from-utf-8-stored-in-varchar/)